# HTML Email from <a> tag with PhoneGap

Tags: html, cordova, html-email

Im developing a mobile application using PhoneGap. In this application the user should be  able to click a link to send an email from there and this email should contain HTML data. So what I have is something like this:

JS:

```
var mail = "<html><body><h1>Testing HTML Email</h1></body></html>"
$("#mailTo").attr("href", "mailto:?subject=Star&body=" + mail);
```

HTML (PhoneGap):

```
<a id="mailTo" href="#">Email</a>
```

When I click the link, the Gmail app on my phone (Im using android) opens with the content of the variable mail but it is not interpreted as HTML. I would like to know if there is a way to do so (set headers or something like that). Thanks in advance.

Comment: [This thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620324/mailto-with-html-body) suggests it's generally not possible, though some email clients may support a subset of HTML tags.

Comment: You should also try URL-encoding your `mail` parameter.

Comment: You can use this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10172499/mailto-using-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, according to the specification the body is meant to be `text/plain`:

> The special hname "body" indicates that the associated hvalue is
> the    body of the message. The "body" hname should contain the
> content for    the first text/plain body part of the message. The
> mailto URL is    primarily intended for generation of short text
> messages that are    actually the content of automatic processing
> (such as "subscribe"    messages for mailing lists), not general MIME
> bodies.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2368

Comment: Humm thanks... Any ideas on how I should proceed then? Send the data to a server through HTTP request and then from the server send the email maybe?

Comment: @JoãoMenighin Sure that would be a good solution. To get similar results your could then set the `reply-to` header so that replies go to the user that "sent" the email.