# Jscript redirection to SMS editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, jscript

Is there a way to redirect user from web page to sms editor with a time delay? Something like this:

```
function Redirect() {
           window.location="http://www.tutorialspoint.com";
        }

        document.write("You will be redirected to main page in 10 sec.");
        setTimeout('Redirect()', 10000);
```

only instead of the "http://www.tutorialspoint.com" using "sms:?body=Hello world" for example?

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10172499/mailto-using-javascript

Comment: @Locercus I've tried but it's not working with "sms:", just with "mailto:".

Comment: Correction: it's actually not working just in Chrome.

Comment: That might be a feature/bug in Chrome. See http://superuser.com/questions/451350/chrome-doesn-t-handle-custom-protocols-correctly

Answer (score 0):

After a few tests on different browsers, I've came out with this:

```
function Redirect() {
       window.location.href="sms:?body=Hello world";
    }

    document.write("You will be redirected to main page in 10 sec.");
    setTimeout('Redirect()', 10000);
```

This is working in Android but I guess it could be modified to work with IOS also.
Please notice: sms:& for iOS 8, sms:; for iOS 5,6 and sms:? for Android.