# when click mail icon mail will be open with this mailid

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, css

[image]when click mail icon mail will be open with this mailid

I am developing one project. In that when I click the mail icon the mail signup page will be open with that mail id.

In below picture red border mention mail icon clicked the page will be redirect to mail signup page with this mail id as username

Comment: @soorapadman ya exactly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mailto using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10172499/mailto-using-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using JS you can fill the parameters

```
window.open('mailto:your_mail@example.com?subject=subject&body=body');
```

Check here: [How to send an email from JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381150/how-to-send-an-email-from-javascript)

Comment: Thanks for your update