# Show only the text string from a Html-form

Tags: html, post, mailto

I'm set up a Html-form which send a form with the mailto action.
I want that the String from the Textfield only appears and not the form format.

It would be great if the method is only made in Html.

```
<html>

<head>
  <title>Title of the
    document
  </title>
</head>

<body>
  <h2>Title</h2>
  <form action="mailto:mailadress@mail.com"
    method="post" enctype="text/plain">
    <p>Nachricht:
      <br />
      <textarea name=" " rows="12"
        cols="35"></textarea>
      <br>
      <p><input type="submit"
          name=" " value="Send" />
        <input type="reset"
          name="reset" value="Clear Form" />
      </p>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

The actual results are:

```
Text= Textstring from textarea
Send=Send
```

My expected results should be:

```
Textstring from textarea
```

Comment: I don't think that's possible, unless, of course, you use a bit of Javascript.
In which case, you may take a look a this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10172499/mailto-using-javascript

Comment: Ok, thanks for the comment and the link. I try and update if i get some nice results.