# How to use mailto function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, web, web-development-server

How do I use the "mailto" function in JavaScript for a table containing product details

```
function SendEmail() {
  var email = document.getElemenById("list").value;
  window.location.href = "mailto:example@gmail.com?subject=enquiry &body=+ "email"";
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mailto using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10172499/mailto-using-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing in your function is correct, but it has errors.

`getElemenById` should be `getElementById` (add the 't')

`"mailto:example@gmail.com?subject=enquiry &body=+ "email""`
should be

`"mailto:example@gmail.com?subject=enquirt&body=" + email` (remove space in between "enquirt" and "&body", correctly format end)

Finished function:

```
function SendEmail() {
  var email = document.getElementById("list").value;
  window.location.href = "mailto:example@gmail.com?subject=enquiry&body=" + email;
}
```